# How do I get just the user-manual for Vim

Tags: linux, bash, vim, vi

To get the vim user-manual I am doing

```
vi test
```

and then, once the file is opened, I do

:help user-manual

This opens up a split window, which makes reading manual inconvenient to read. How do I only open the user-manual in the full window ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
:h user-manual | only
```

**only** : Make the current window the only one on the screen.  All other
            windows are closed.

See: `:h only`

---

*Open* from *terminal*:

```
vi[m] -c 'h user-manual|only'
```

Answer (score 2):

After opening the user manual, type `:only` to close all other windows.

Or, you can just [read the manual online](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_toc.html) at [VimDoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/).