# How to enter vim user manual without being in VIM

Tags: vim

I want to simply browse the VIM user-manual, but the only way I get access is by opening a session of vim and the typing: `help user-manual`. The problem with this is that this ends up creating a screen split which is not comfortable for reading, especially when I don't even need the empty file below.

I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> will fix this issue, but I'm running Linux from my Chromebook and Chrome overrides the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut (close current tab).

So would there be a way I can open up the user-manual by itself? And if not, could anyone suggest a clever hack?

One thing I did try to do was create a copy of the manual and open that up in `vim`, but this didn't allow any of the links to function.

Comment: Just noticed in "Related" that this Q is asked and answered [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15640/how-do-i-get-just-the-user-manual-for-vim?rq=1)

Comment: Got it. I'll make sure to look around some more before asking again.

Answer (score 5):

The `vim` command line switch `-c` will execute vim commands.
You can pass multiple commands and passing the two following commands will start **help**, in **only** one window

```
vim -c help -c only
```

Comment: How do you go to a specific page in the user-manual? I tried 
`vim -c help usr_05.txt -c only` but that just takes you to the start of **help.txt**. So you still need to move your cursor to the tag for the page title in the table of contents and jump to it with <CTRL-]>

Comment: Try quoting the chapter, together with the help command, vim -c 'help usr_05.txt'

Comment: Okay that worked. I guess commands that take an argument need to be wrapped in double quotes, which is great because now I can jump straight to a specific section with the tag command, `:ta`. Say I want to view just section 7.2 of the user manual, then I could run `vim -c help -c "ta 07.2" -c only`